# Java Web Apps virtual host

Tags: java, deployment

I have just became a partner of a company that has a site developed in JAVA. As part of the agreement they allow me to create a section on their site (so I can take benefit of their traffic), but the development of this section needs to be as less intrusive as possible.

So ideally I would like to implement an independant web application in JAVA (with same layout) with a separate database that runs in the same application server. And in the application server to make a mapping like this:

All the traffic that comes to www.domain.com/MY_FOLDER
its served by my web application, all the rest should be served by my partners site.

I have no experience in JAVA but I found that in php this can be done, so I was wondering if it can be done also in JAVA. 
About the application server I dont know yet which one they are using but I guess that are using "resing server" (by caucho: http://www.caucho.com/).

I would really appreciate if you can give me any ideas of how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Answer (score 0):

Only one application can listen at a given socket at one time, so you need to have the existing server forward "your" requests to your web application, if it is not Java capable in itself.

The way to do that is not standardized so you will have to talk to the server administrator.

The easiest way to start from scratch with a Java Web Application is in the Netbeans bundle with Glassfish.